# Tweepy Authentication vs. Authorization

Tags: twitter, oauth-2.0, twitter-oauth, tweepy

I have Oath working with Facebook, Google, and Twitter; however, I am having an issue with the latter where it uses an "authorization" URL each time rather than "authentication".  The result is that the user is asked to authorize my app each time.  With both Google and FB once the app is authorized they are not asked again when they log in.  It is aware behind the scenes if the user is logged into one of those services and if so (and they already authorized my app) it logs them immediately into my app.  With Twitter it will take them to an authorization screen each time.

I know this is due to the flow I have with Twitter which which says:  redirect_url = auth.get_authorization_url() followed by a self.redirect(redirect_url)

The key above is "authorization" which is unaware of the user's acceptance of my app previously.    In Twitter I know there is a checkbox to "allow this application to be used to sign in with Twitter".  This is checked.  What I am not able to find is the correct path with Tweepy that checks whether the user is already logged into Twitter and has already authorized my app.

I do save the tokens that Twitter sent back with the user at first authorization, however, I have no idea who the user is until they login so I cannot try to use these tokens for this initial part of the exercise.  I should note that I don't have to use the tokens from Google or FB either at this stage.

Can Tweepy be used in the manner described above or do I need to do something else?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fortunately, there is a very simple solution. When calling `api.get_authorization_url`, simply specify `signin_with_twitter=True` as a keyword argument. Your call should look like this:

```
api.get_authorization_url(signin_with_twitter=True)
```

This causes Tweepy to use the 'authentication`endpoint you mentioned, instead of the`authorization` endpoint.

Comment: I didn't think this one was going to get answered.  This works perfectly, thanks so much!  Was this in the docs somewhere that I missed or where did you come across this?  Thanks again!

Comment: @C6Silver: You're welcome :). I'm going through all of the unanswered questions tagged 'tweepy', and adding answers.